# Can't render multiple responsive canvas graphs in different tabs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have different graphs in different tabs (bootstrap nav-pill tabs) of my page. When I set the graphs to responsive, the width and height properties of the inactive tabs are calculated as being zero and therefore the inactive graphs are not rendered. I tried to define and render the graphs on a click event, but this didn't work.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/17nhjjp9/

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one" class="blue-tabs">One</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two" class="blue-tabs">Two</a></li>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="one" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="tab-pane fade">
        <canvas id="myChart2" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>

</div>


var data = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "red",
            strokeColor: "red",
            pointColor: "red",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "red",
            data: [40, 35, 38, 40, 35, 40,]
        }
    ]
};

var data2 = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "red",
            strokeColor: "red",
            pointColor: "red",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "red",
            data: [25, 25, 25, 25, 35, 25,]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, { responsive: true });
var myLineChart2 = new Chart(ctx2).Line(data2, { responsive: true });
```

What can be done to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I edited you fiddle to make it work (in bootstrap 2). Render the charts on tab shown as @rukimira supposed. http://jsfiddle.net/17nhjjp9/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to redraw your chart each time you switched between tabs.
If you just resize your window, you'll see the chart being rendered...

Invoke some trigger to destroy myLineChart2 then just init it once again.